# How do I copy formatted formula results in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have formula cells outputting numerical results that are then formatted with a `" km"` (kilometres) post-fix. For example, the formula returns `21.4`, which is then formatted as `21,4 km`. I want to copy and paste the numerical value, so I copy and then on the target cell select "Paste values only". But this assigns the cell with a text value of `"21,4 km"`, and I need the numerical value `21.4` instead. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way to do this. Consider this sheet below.

> [image]
>
> `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A13:A16,"(\d+.\d+)"))`

For a series of numbers we can do this.

For a single cell, use `=REGEXEXTRACT(A13, "(\d+.\d+)")` assuming the value is in A13

**Edit: As suggested by [Oleg S](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/239790/oleg-s), the final step is to use the `VALUE()` function to get the numerical value. So far it's just text.**

Revised formula: `=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A13,"\d+.\d+")` for a single cell.

And for the whole column `=ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A13:A16,"\d+.\d+")))`

Replace the values `A13` and `A16` accordingly. `A13` is the first cell, `A16` is the last cell. You may also write it as `A13:A` and that will take all the rows starting for A13 under consideration.

Comment: Also add VALUE() to get numbers not text.

Comment: @OlegS Yes, thanks. May I add your comment in my answer?

Comment: For sure add it.